# Isdate javascript code

Tags: javascript, vb.net, firefox, date

When the user types date as 05/04 in the textbox and presses enter, i am using the following code to check whether it is a date. And the code is

```
 window.execScript("dim successReturn:successReturn=Isdate('" + ctl.value + "')","VBScript");
```

This works fine for IE, If I enter 05/04 , it returns as true. But the code is not working in other browsers. Please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the following code.

```
var comp = "05/04".split('/');
var d = parseInt(comp[0], 10);
var m = parseInt(comp[1], 10);
var date = new Date(null, m - 1, d);
var validDateFormat = false;
if (date.getMonth() + 1 == m && date.getDate() == d) {
    validDateFormat = true;
}
```

validDateFormat will be true if the date is correct. Do note that dd/mm format is taken into consideration in the above code.

Comment: `x=false; if(y){x=true};` can be simplified to `x=y` or (if you need to cast to boolean) `x=!!y`.

Answer (score 1):

[`window.execScript`](http://help.dottoro.com/ljoswolk.php) is an IE-only method. It is not supported in Firefox, Safari or Opera. Dottoro.com claims Chrome support, but it is no longer true (if it ever was). [Another resource](http://javascript.gakaa.com/window-execscript-4-0-5-.aspx) claims no support whatsoever from any of the major browsers except IE4+. MDN claims no support except for IE.

As far as I know, there is *no* way to execute VBscript by any other browser than Internet Explorer. Barring javascript libraries that perform interpretation, of course - but I'm not aware of such libraries either. You will have to translate - or compile - your VBscript to javascript.

Concerning your code, see [Ali's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15971256/499214) of parsing the date manually.

Comment: Thanks for your very valuable info. :)